# Does Ubuntu support Toshiba L50 -C-12V (PSKWNE)

Tags: 15.04, toshiba-satellite

I'm new to the world of web design, development and programming and I was thinking of trying out a Linux OS. After researching for a few weeks I've come to the conclusion that Ubuntu would be the best one. However, I bought a Toshiba L50-C-12V last month and I need to know if it will work with my hardware fully or if I will at least be able to get ubuntu compatible drivers for my hardware. I know that people have asked similar questions but I am not looking basics, I want to be able to run Ubuntu without any problems. The Link below will take you to the specifications for the exact make and model of my laptop. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
[Laptop Specs](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/laptops/satellite/satellite-l50-c/satellite-l50-c-12v/)

Comment: We are not a hardware support site ;) General idea is that you test yourself and make your own decision as "working" is a matter of opinion (I do not mind not being able to use software X where you consider it vital). Please download Ubuntu , put it on a dvd or usb, boot into the live session and try it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware compatibility question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked your specs, and in my opinion all modern linux distros will support them, ubuntu included. Most hardware setups dont need proprietary drivers in linux unlike windows, so yea as Rinzwind also said i would suggest you to try ubuntu. Just be sure to use `14.04 LTS` version rather than the latest one as it is the most compatible one.

Comment: "Most hardware setups dont need proprietary drivers in linux unlike windows" Not true, any system with Nvidia or AMD gpu will NEED drivers, also wireless wlan, amongst others, could need drivers, depending on the model. The only way to find out is to test it and ask here4 about an issues you face.

Comment: @mark kirby i will have to differ here mark, open source drivers do work good even with amd or nvidia gpu and they come preinstalled on most distros. Proprietary drivers do exist for such i know but they are not a necessity unless you want to play a game or do some graphics intensive task. Linux has evolved a lot and most hardwares WILL work ootb in modern distros. Windows however is totally different case, even with most basic setups you will be riddled with driver problems.

Comment: I agree with you, my comment was merely as clarification for the OP, they probably will need some kind of driver in the end on there system, sorry for down voting you, your explanation is more than acceptable, please make any kind of small edit so I can subtract my vote.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same laptop, pretty much, though I've doubled the RAM to 16 GBs. It has Linux Mint, Cinnamon, on it. Mint is a fork of Ubuntu and shares the same repositories. It works just fine so it will *probably* work with Ubuntu as well.

In fact, I did have Ubuntu on it for a short spell. I broke the OS and did not take the time to fix it. That is how I ended up with Mint on it but, importantly, the breakage was due to my own error and the OS was fine otherwise for the short time that it was installed.

I needed no special configuration nor did I need to install the proprietary drivers (IIRC) to get it working. It was a fairly simple install though I did not partition it or set it up to use a /swap partition.

Hope that helps. Good luck.